# mySQL GROUP, most recent

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the data set:

`Person Status   Date
 Eric    1     1/1/2015
 Eric    2     2/1/2015
 Eric    3     3/1/2015
 John    1     3/1/2015
 John    2     2/1/2015
 John    1     1/1/2015`

I'd like to get the most recent date, and its correlated status, grouped by Person. I tried using a subquery to first identify the most recent date:

`SELECT MAX(Date), Person FROM tbl1 GROUP BY Person`

And then joining that back into the original table, so that by person I know which date is the most recent. But I'm struggling how to identify the most recent status. I just don't see the appropriate aggregator. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select tbl1.*
from tbl1
join
(
    SELECT Person, MAX(Date) as m_date 
    FROM tbl1 
    GROUP BY Person
) tmp on tbl1.Person = tmp.Person
     and tbl1.date = tmp.m_date
```

Comment: Ohh man, you are genius...I was working on this for almost 2 hours. Very clear