# Insert into table only if most recent record from group is different

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following columns:

```
score_id (int10, auto_increment, primary key); 
game_id (int10); 
away_team_score (int10); 
home_team_score (int10); 
date_time (datetime);
```

I am scraping a web API (using python) which I am trying to write an array to this database. However, each time I read this API it provides a list of all events. I am trying to write to this database only when there is a difference in either the away_team_score or the home_team_score for each game_id.

I am able to get the most-recent records using the query from this example ([mySQL GROUP, most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306192/mysql-group-most-recent)). However, I am unsure on how to check if the values that I am inserting are the same.

I don't want to use update because I want to keep the scores for historical purposes. Also, if the game_id does not exist, it should insert it.

My python code I currently have:

```py
# Connecting to the mysql database
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="examplehost", user="exampleuser", passwd="examplepassword", database="exampledb")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
# example scores array that I scraped
# It is in the format of game_id, away_team_score, home_team_score, date_time
scores = [[1, 0, 1, '2019-11-30 13:05:00'], [2, 1, 5, '2019-11-30 13:05:00'], [3, 4, 8, '2019-11-30 13:05:00'],
          [4, 6, 1, '2019-11-30 13:05:00'], [5, 0, 2, '2019-11-30 13:05:00']]

# Inserting into database
game_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_scores (game_id, away_team_score, home_team_score, date_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"

mycursor.executemany(game_query, scores)
mydb.commit()

mydb.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of UPSERT functionality in MySQL. 
Changing your insert query to the following query will only insert when there is new game-id, else it will update the scores:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_scores
    (game_id, score_id, away_team_score, home_team_score, date_time)
VALUES
    (game_id, score_id, away_team_score, home_team_score, date_time)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    game_id = game_id,
    away_team_score = away_team_score,
    home_team_score = home_team_score,
    date_time = date_time;
```

Details on upsert - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Questions: if the primary key is an auto-increment, how would there ever be a duplicate key? Also, I should have specified that the date_time in my array is the current date, so it will always be changing.

Comment: You need to add another constraints on table "Unique Key" on 3 columns - game_id, away_team_score and home_tean_score, then on duplicate will detect whether it needs to update or insert.

Comment: Oh, whoops. I did not know primary key != unique key. I will go ahead and try this. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, in almost every database we can have multiple keys/constraints (like Primary, Unique, Foreign, Not Null)

Comment: Thank you, @Hussain Bohra. This is working greatly. Thank you!